# SCons builder changes working directory to target file directory

Tags: python, scons

I'm faced with the following situation. There is the simplest example of SCons builder (that does almost nothing) and pseudobuilder:

```
#------------------------------------------------
#
#   Builder
#
def slon(target, source, env):

    print(os.getcwd())

    return None

#------------------------------------------------
#
#   Pseudobuilder
#
def launch_slon(env, src):

    trg = src + '.kot'
      
    return env.Slon(trg, src, env)

#------------------------------------------------

#------------------------------------------------
#
#   Register builders
#
Slon     = Builder(action = slon)

Builders = { 'Slon' : Slon }

env.Append(BUILDERS = Builders)

env.AddMethod(launch_slon, 'LaunchSlon')

...

#------------------------------------------------
#
#   SConsript
#

Import('envx')

...
slon  = envx.LaunchSlon('/opt/pro/fw-snmp/src/sw/main.cpp')

envx.Alias('slon', slon)
```

And launch scons:

```
$scons --debug=explain slon

scons: building `src/sw/main.cpp.kot' because it doesn't exist
os.chdir('src/sw')
slon(["src/sw/main.cpp.kot"], ["src/sw/main.cpp"])
/opt/pro/fw-snmp/src/sw
os.chdir('/opt/pro/fw-snmp')
```

As said in SCons documentation the build process is performed from project root directory - where SConstruct resides (`/opt/pro/fw-snmp` in this case). But SCons performs working directory change to target file directory. That is SCons behavior is as if the `chdir=1` option was specified for builder. But is wasn't. This breaks my build process (first, file path lookup doesn't work).

What is the reason of such SCons behavior?

Thank you.

UPDATE.

Here is an archive with the above example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1USBbMrXtldrYyz0pc49QYmfV0kcZowzs/view?usp=sharing.

Just launch from terminal:

```
SCONSFLAGS=-D scons variant=slon1 slon
```

The result:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
********************************************************************************
                           build variant: slon1
********************************************************************************

target: ../../../src/sw/main.cpp.kot    |   source: ../../../src/sw/main.cpp
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
os.chdir('src/sw')
slon(["src/sw/main.cpp.kot"], ["src/sw/main.cpp"])
/opt/ssd/pro/slon/scons-bugs/2/scons-chdir/src/sw
os.chdir('/opt/ssd/pro/slon/scons-bugs/2/scons-chdir')
scons: done building targets.
```

UPDATE2.

The above example code as git repo:

https://github.com/harryzhurov/scons-chdir

Comment: Please complete your example code. It's not runnable as is. Perhaps make a repo on github and share that?

Comment: Where is "os.chdir('src/sw')" coming from? What is your SConscript() call?  What is LaunchSlon()'s definition?

Comment: I have added complete example (original message was updated). Thank you.

Comment: @bdbaddog Please, do not encourage other users to link to external sites instead of providing the code. The question should contain all the code necessary to reproduce the problem. Asking for a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example is fine but it should be pasted here because external links tend to expire after a time.

Comment: @HarryZhurov Please, make sure you code works when it is copied from here and pasted to a `SConstruct`.

Comment: @NO_NAME Such simple method as copy-paste the code to SConstruct cannot reproduce the problem because in this case there is no hierarchical build and so there are no directory changes. But just the "parasitic" directory change (during build phase) is the issue.

Comment: @HarryZhurov If you need more files or some directory to exist, you can describe them. It doesn't have to be a single file. What I've meant is that right now the code gives an error `NameError: name 'env' is not defined:` which I'm pretty sure isn't the problem you're asking about. For more information about designing examples for questions read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @NO_NAME Only contents of the files is not sufficient - directory tree is important, too. Therefore, complete working example is preferable, IMHO. `NameError: name 'env' is not defined:`, where this issue raises? This example code have been tested on different PC before posting.

Comment: @HarryZhurov When you're saying the example is working, do you mean the code you've included in the question or the entire project you've linked to? The code from the question definitely raises that error. You've use variable `env` there and you don't create it anywhere.

Comment: @NO_NAME I mean code in linked archive which contains minimal example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @NO_NAME - I get that you're concerned about linked pages/repos going away. But this question's issue depends on a directory structure.  I suppose the original poster can attach a zip file to this question?

Comment: Or just bring the question to the scons-users mailing where we won't care if you point to an external site.. ;)

Comment: @bdbaddog They can describe the directory structure and paste the necessary files as code here AND provide a link to external repository for people who don't want to put it together manually. (I don't quite believe all those files are required to reproduce the issue.) The idea of Stack Overflow is that not only the OP gets the answer but other people with similar problem can easily find it as well. Having a question with a code that does neither work not reproduce the issue doesn't do it.

Comment: @bdbaddog Is the code in archive by URL or in git repo sufficient to reproduce the issue with `os.chdir`?

Comment: Can anybody confirm or refute described behavior of the posted example? I've tested the code on several different PC and results are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I've exercised some tests and found that Top directory (where SConstruct should be resided) also changed to target build directory during build phase. To see this I've added debug prints to the builder action function:

```
#
# The action function
#
def slon(target, source, env):

    print('>>> Project root directory:   ', os.path.abspath(str(env.Dir('#'))))
    print('>>> Current working directory:', os.getcwd())

    return None
```

Output is (project absolute path is '/opt/scons-chdir'):

```
$ scons   
scons: Entering directory `/opt/scons-chdir`
...
os.chdir('build')
slon(["build/main.cpp.kot"], ["src/sw/main.cpp"])
>>> Project root directory:    /opt/scons-chdir/build
>>> Current working directory: /opt/scons-chdir/build
os.chdir('/opt/scons-chdir')
```

`SConstruct` file is resided in '/opt/scons-chdir'.

This explains why `scons` change directory to `build` during build phase, but it's still not clear why `scons` thinks that `build` is project root directory.

Can anybody explains such behavior?

The above code example is available here: https://github.com/harryzhurov/scons-chdir